# What does division by 1e9d mean?

Tags: java, time, nanotime, datetime-conversion

This is the snippet:

```
String myTime = someTime / 1e9d + ",";
```

`someTime` is derived by using `System.nanoTime()`. What does `1e9d` do here?

Comment: 10^9 as a double (kind of redundant).

Comment: It's in nano second, so you'll have 1 000 000 000 ns every 1 second. If you want to display the time in plain seconds, you'll have to divide it by 10e9

Comment: 1e9d is scientific notation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1e9` means 10^9 
`2d` means 2 as double

e.g.

- sysout `1e9` => 1.0E9
- sysout `10e9` => 1.0E10

See also the [Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) section of *The Java™ Tutorials*.

Comment: How will I express 1.0e-3 on the same lines? '1e-3d'? It doesn't give me any error.

Comment: @user1071840 Or simply `1e-3`

Answer (score 2):

The suffix d denotes a double number. If the number wasn't treated as a floating point number, then the division would be considered an integer division, returning an integer (e.g. 3/2=1).

1e9 is simply 10^9. The conversion seems to be from nanoseconds to seconds.

--EDIT--

**Ingo** correctly points out that 10e9 is already evaluated by java to a double (see [this part of the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) for details). Therefore the 'd' isn't needed in this case.

Comment: You should perhaps add that the notation `10e9` is already enough to establis that it is a double, at least in Java. Hence the `d` suffix is really superfluous here.